# Accidentally installed Anaconda in two places

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I accidentally installed the Python Anaconda distribution in two different place: my home directory and my hard drive. Since I installed it on my hard drive first, the python packages were being installed there instead of in my home directory. I then deleted to the anaconda folder on my hard drive. But now when I try to run conda to install a package via my terminal, I get the following error.

```
-bash: //anaconda/bin/conda: No such file or directory
```

How would I switch it so that conda works and installs the packages in my home directory?

I did the command

```
echo $PATH
```

and it gave me

```
//anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin.
```

Also, I did

```
which -a conda
```

and nothing showed up. I literally just bought a Macbook Air and am on Yosemite.

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $PATH`  and `which -a conda` to your question. Also some information about your OS will be useful.

Comment: echo $PATH IS //anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin and which -a conda doesn't show anything. I literally just bought a Macbook Air and installed Anaconda as one of my first installations

Comment: Please add this information by editing your question. Comments come and go :)

Comment: Great thanks. Sorry, I'm an SO newbie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anaconda adds itself to the `PATH` variable in your `~/.bash_profile`. If you open this file with your favorite editor, you will find something like this:

```
# added by Miniconda 3.6.0 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

If you adapt this to `export PATH="<path-to-your-anaconda-in-home>/bin:$PATH"`, `conda` should work again.

e.g for me it's:

```
# added by Miniconda 3.6.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/ch/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: It says that I don't own the .bash_profile and I don't have permission to write to it. It says that I can create a duplicate though.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: sure its : -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  72 Sep 28 17:09 /Users/Dan/.bash_profile

Comment: `sudo chown Dan /Users/Dan/.bash_profile`. This file should belong to your user.

Comment: Ok finally edited it it to say this: 

# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH=“/Users/Dan/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

But when I go to source the file, I get these errors:

-bash: .bash_profile: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: .bash_profile: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Your first quotation mark looks weird. Make sure, you use the simple ones `“` != `"`.